# Replace multiple dashes with one dash

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have a string which looks like this:

```
something-------another--thing
       //^^^^^^^       ^^
```

I want to replace the multiple dashes with a single one.

So the expected output would be:

```
something-another-thing
       //^       ^
```

I tried to use `str_replace()`, but I have to write the code again for every possible amount of dashes. So how can I replace any amount of dashes with a single one?

**For Rizier:**

Tried:

```
 $mystring = "something-------another--thing";
 str_replace("--", "-", $mystring);
 str_replace("---", "-", $mystring);
 str_replace("----", "-", $mystring);
 str_replace("-----", "-", $mystring);
 str_replace("------", "-", $mystring);
 str_replace("-------", "-", $mystring);
 str_replace("--------", "-", $mystring);
 str_replace("---------", "-", $mystring);
 etc...
```

But the string could have 10000 of lines between two words.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: @Rizier123 He said he tried `str_replace`

Comment: @Barmar I know, but I read that too many times and OP never edited their question with their attempts. So now I want to see the code and not only read "I tried"

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` to replace a pattern.

```
$str = preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $str);
```

The regular expression `-+` matches any sequence of 1 or more hyphen characters.

If you don't understand regular expressions, read the tutorial at [www.regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expression.info).

Answer (score 7):

you can use

```
<?php
$string="something-------another--thing";
echo $str = preg_replace('/-{2,}/','-',$string);
```

Output

```
something-another-thing
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have a string with multiple Charakters to clean use this:

```
$string="Hello,,,my text contains unused characters... What can i do???"
$newString=preg_replace('#([\-\.\?])\\1+#','$1',$string);
```

if you have a string with unknown multiple signs to clean use this:

```
$string="!!!!A string with ooooother unknoooooown multiple Signs!!!!"
$newString=preg_replace('#([.])\\1+#','$1',$string);
```